# Fix error with skforecast and pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

I'm trying to run: `from skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg import ForecasterAutoreg` and i have this error

```
from skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg import ForecasterAutoreg
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skforecast'
```

I run `C:\Users\Yanina\Prueba>pip3 install skforecast` and this happens

```
building 'statsmodels.tsa._stl' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for statsmodels
Failed to build statsmodels
ERROR: Could not build wheels for statsmodels, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Yanina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When i run `pip` for `pyproject.toml` it apparently works just fine.
So i think the issue is with `skforecast` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Which version on Windows are you using? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
2. Scroll down and search for "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022" (see image)
   [image]
3. Run the downloaded app and Install "Desktop development with C++". I also installed some individual packages in the "Individual components" tab but I am not sure if it is needed or not (try it). In any case, to the right of the image you have the packages I installed.
   [image]